# ARB shader ballot : not coherent between false and true?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vulkan

I am wondering why `ballotARB(false)` returns always 0 and not return the bitfield where the corresponding bits are set for all active invocations in the sub-group.

Because of that, I do not see how can I use ballotARB fonction in my program.

Is my understanding of this function false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What *should* `ballotARB(false)` return, if not `0`?

It does return the count of the `true` votes in the local subgroup. Since all your invocations vote `false` no matter what, the result *must* be `0`. This is even explicitely stated in the [`ARB_shader_ballot`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_ballot.txt) extension spec:

> The following trivial assumptions can be made:
>
> - `ballotARB(true)` returns `bitfield` where the corresponding bits are set for all active invocations in the sub-group.
> - **`ballotARB(false)` returns zero.**

So to make use of the votes, you should use it on an experession which is actually not *dynamically uniform*.

Comment: Okay I misexplain my problem. If I have 25 invocations that vote `true` and 7 that vote `false`. A thread that vote `true` will get the `bitfield where the corresponding bits are set for all active invocations in the sub-group.`. However in my understanding ofthe spec, if a thread vote false, it will get always 0 even if other invocation vote true

Comment: Ah okay. These 2 assumptions are made only for the case where we wrote explicitely true or false. Thanks !